# which extension should i use for rating system in yii?

Tags: netbeans, yii, yii-extensions, rating, yii1.x

I am currently implementing rating and reviewing system in my project which is made in `yii`, `netbeans`. I want to use `yii` `extension`, but I do not have any idea,about any rating extension. Please I need your suggestions. which extension should I choose so that in future I  would be able to find the helping material easily on this extension.I want to implement `star` `rating`.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to yii. In this hypothesis you can try this extension:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dzraty/

or this

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pcstarranking/

depend on your neeed

the first is a wrapper for  http://yii.dezero.es/dzraty
probably is the  more interesting.